# Select only some columns from a table on a JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Is it possible to select only some columns from a table on a JOIN? (Any kind.)

Answer (score 59):

Of course.  Just list the columns you want to select as you would in any query:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (...)
```

Note that I've included the `table1.` or `table2.` prefix on all columns to be sure there aren't any ambiguities where fields with the same name exist in both tables.

Comment: Probably worth adding that it's a good idea to prefix them with the table they're from e.g. table1.column1, table2.column2 etc so stop ambiguity errors and just for general readability.

Comment: Also, if you have any ambiguous column names, you can specify which table to use with dot syntax: SELECT table1.id, table2.name FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (...)

Comment: I want to select the columns from the table I'm about to join, not from the first table.

Comment: @Psyche: It's no different. As Vorey depicts, table2.column3 is coming from the joined table, not the original source table.

Answer (score 57):

Add a `*` to just that table in your select statement, separate from other columns with a comma:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.col2, table2.col3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON...
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492919/3417198

Comment: finally the answer I was looking for. Of course one can specify each column in each nested select but it often happens that you need to cascade 5 or more subqueries in order to append different columns to your main temporary table, and it is such a pain to rewrite and track all the columns in each subquery. This solves it

Answer (score 13):

If you want some of table1's columns and some of table2's columns, you would do something like

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful if you are facing data integrity issues e.g. product has same ID but different descriptions across 2 tables / data sources
A work-around is to use CASE statement in your query
Following query will Return Rows where col a is matching across both tables but column b may not be the same in table t2.

```
-- CREATE SAMPLE DATA
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.t1
(
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text
);
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.t2
(
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text
);
    
--truncate t1;
--truncate t2;
insert into t1 values ('1-1','1-1','1-c1','1-d1');
insert into t1 values ('1-2','1-2','1-c2','1-d2');
insert into t1 values ('1-3','1-3','1-c3','1-d3');
insert into t1 values ('1-1','1-4','1-c4','1-d4');
insert into t2 values ('1-1','1-1','2-c1','2-d1');
insert into t2 values ('1-2','1-2','2-c2','2-d2');
insert into t2 values ('1-3','2-b3','2-c3','2-d3');
insert into t2 values ('2-a4','2-b4','2-c4','2-d4');

-- QUERY THAT YOU ARE POSSIBLY LOOKING FOR
select * from
(
    select 
t1.a as a1, t1.b as b1, t1.c as c1, t1.d as d1
, t2.a as a2, 
case 
when t1.b <> t2.b then NULL
else t2.b
END b2,
case 
when t1.b <> t2.b then NULL
else t2.c
END c2,
case 
when t1.b <> t2.b then NULL
else t2.d
END d2

-- ,t2.c as c2, t2.d as d2
from t1
LEFT join t2 on t1.a = t2.a 
    ) as x
-- where b2 is null -- This is in case you want only rows where first key matches but second does not
```