# MySQL Select all columns from one table and some from another table

Tags: select, mysql, join

How do you select all the columns from one table and just some columns from another table using JOIN? In MySQL.

Answer (score 658, accepted):

Just use the table name:

```
SELECT myTable.*, otherTable.foo, otherTable.bar...
```

That would select all columns from `myTable` and columns `foo` and `bar` from `otherTable`.

Comment: and if you want to use the count(myTable.*) how does that work?

Comment: you can also use aliases, so when you go select * from tablename as tn, you could write select tn.* from tablename as tn.

Comment: My MySql DB dont need to prefix fields from other tables. Ex: SELECT table1.*, field1InTable2, field1InTable3, field2InTable3 from table1 join table2 on .... join table3 on ..., works!

Comment: Nah, that creates tons of "duplicate" rows

Answer (score 56):

I need more information really but it will be along the lines of..

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.col1, table2.col3 FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING(id)
```

Answer (score 33):

`select a.* , b.Aa , b.Ab, b.Ac 
 from table1 a 
 left join table2 b on a.id=b.id`

this should select all columns from table 1 and only the listed columns from table 2 joined by id.

Answer (score 5):

Using alias for referencing the tables to get the columns from different tables after joining them.

```
Select tb1.*, tb2.col1, tb2.col2 from table1 tb1 JOIN table2 tb2 on tb1.Id = tb2.Id
```

Comment: Good answer, helpful indeed!