# Mysql Select All from one table, and some from another table Using Aliases

Tags: php, mysql

I'm posting this question because I did manage to find [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492904/mysql-select-all-columns-from-one-table-and-some-from-another-table), but they weren't using aliases.

I have two tables - I want to grab everything from `table1` and just grab the `user_name` and `Team` from `table2`.

My original query is grabbing everything from `table2`

```
SELECT * 
FROM qabin.allqas t1 
JOIN login.users t2 
ON (t1.Submitter = t2.user_name) 
WHERE t1.Status='Complete'
```

That's all well and good and works fine, but I would like to just get the `user_name` and the `Team`

To make things more interesting, they are in different databases, though it hasn't been an issue.

One is in the `qabin` database and the other is in the `login` database.

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
  qabin.allqas.* AS t1,
  login.users.Team,
  login.users.user_name
JOIN login.users t2
ON (t1.Submitter = t2.user_name)
WHERE t1.Status='Complete'
```

I need the t1 and t2 aliases because they are used elsewhere for building a larger query string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you pointed out the other question its useful to know that you can follow that answer and just substitute the aliases for the table names

Comment: I was trying to avoid this as there are many, many lines of code that use those aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a subquery?

```
SELECT * 
FROM qabin.allqas t1 
JOIN (SELECT user_name, Team FROM login.users) t2 
ON (t1.Submitter = t2.user_name) 
WHERE t1.Status='Complete'
```

Comment: Awesome, very fast answer and it works :) Also, TIL what subqueries are.

Comment: That's kind of a roundabout way to accomplish something that is much simpler.

Comment: He said that he uses this alias later in a large query. If for some reason he wants only these two fields available to this alias, this is how you do it.

Comment: Ah, you're right. For the simple case it's more than whats needed, but for a more complex query, your answer is nice :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant use one alias (t1) for a set of columns. I guess what you are looking for is something like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.team, t2.user_name
FROM qabin.allqas t1 
JOIN login.users t2 
    ON (t1.Submitter = t2.user_name) 
WHERE t1.Status='Complete'
```

I would recommend using the real column names from t1 instead of t1.*

Comment: I build a string based on a bunch of parameters that are sent, so let me explain what it's used for. Basically another string that appears later is: `$queryString .= "AND t1.DateCompleted BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ";` I was hoping to avoid having to rewrite a bunch of later code

Comment: I'm relatively new to it, but rest assured that I am escaping all post data

Answer (score 1):

Try This query :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.user_name, t2.Team
FROM qabin.allqas t1 
JOIN login.users t2 
ON t1.Submitter 1= t2.user_name
WHERE t1.Status='Complete'
```